# How to make 3d roulette wheel in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

I want to make a 3d roulette wheel in flash.I am using an image of wheel and trying to rotate but when trying to give it a 3d look rotation doesn't work well because image is much like an oval shape.
I am rotating the wheel along its center.
I want my rotating wheel like this [3d rotating wheel](http://activeden.net/item/random-roulette-table-wheel/11012)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Not in Flash. You need every frame of different angles for that rotation.

Comment: are you sure? The link which i have given in my post of 3d roulette wheel has been made in flash only.

Comment: pretty sure. Yes it's made in flash, flash itself does not support 3D. They usually uses vector calculations to simulate 3D. In your case, where you have an image of wheel probably in 2d. It is not possible. What you can try is, spin the wheel and try to capture every frame.

Comment: so i have to use movie clip?

Comment: It'll be your best bet. Instead of trying to create a 3d model of wheel or trying to make come up with a vertex formulae